# difference between multi-line recipes with backslash and multi-line recipes with no backslash in makefile

Tags: c, makefile

In the makefile, what is the difference between

```
targets : prerequisites
        recipe command \
        recipe command \
        ...
```

and

```
targets : prerequisites
        recipe command
        recipe-command
        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From section [5.3 Recipe Execution](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Execution) of the GNU Make manual:

> When it is time to execute recipes to update a target, they are executed by invoking a new sub-shell for each line of the recipe, unless the .ONESHELL special target is in effect (see Using One Shell) (In practice, make may take shortcuts that do not affect the results.)
>
> Please note: this implies that setting shell variables and invoking shell commands such as cd that set a context local to each process will not affect the following lines in the recipe.2 If you want to use cd to affect the next statement, put both statements in a single recipe line. Then make will invoke one shell to run the entire line, and the shell will execute the statements in sequence. For example:
>
> ```
> foo : bar/lose
>         cd $(@D) && gobble $(@F) > ../$@
> ```
>
> Here we use the shell AND operator (&&) so that if the cd command fails, the script will fail without trying to invoke the gobble command in the wrong directory, which could cause problems (in this case it would certainly cause ../foo to be truncated, at least).

The use of backslashes is used to split commands over multiple lines. As explained in detail in section [5.1 Recipe Syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipe-Syntax) of the manual.

> One of the few ways in which make does interpret recipes is checking for a backslash just before the newline. As in normal makefile syntax, a single logical recipe line can be split into multiple physical lines in the makefile by placing a backslash before each newline. A sequence of lines like this is considered a single recipe line, and one instance of the shell will be invoked to run it.

Comment: to be in a single shell, the whole line needs to be surrounded by '(' and ')'

Comment: @user3629249 No, it doesn't. Doing that would launch a (pointless) sub-shell.

Answer (score 4):

When multiple lines are joined by escaping the newline with a backslash, they will all run in the same shell.  This can be important if shell variables are being used.  When each command appears on its own line, they will each run in a new shell.